# Does webring.com have a method of canceling your service?

Tags: website, account-management

I recently joined http://www.webring.com which was a mistake. It is just another crappy website that I'd like to delete my account on? Anyone know how?

They recently enraged me with this amusing paragraph at the bottom of an emai:

> To manage receipt of email, or cancel this account, please visit your My Account area - http://www.webring.com/mbr - **This is an account you created, so there is no "unsubscribe". This is a transactional email under CAN-SPAM guidelines, not commercial or unsolicited email.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow - that site really is bad.

Anyway [from this FAQ article](http://new.webring.com/h/faq#1233095139) you need to do the following:

> **How do I delete my account?**
>
> To delete your WebRing account, you
>   must first quit any WebRing Commuities
>   (rings) in which you are a member.  To
>   do this, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Log into WebRing and view your My Account page.
> 2. Scroll down and click the Memberships tab to open the list of
>      your ring memberships.
> 3. Click on your Site Title(s) to bring up the Edit Site Information
>      page.
> 4. Find and click the "Delete Site from Ring" link in the left column of
>      that page.
> 5. Repeat this process until you have deleted your site(s) from all the
>      rings you belong to. (There is no way
>      to do this for all rings at once.  It
>      must be done one ring at a time.)
>
> If you manage any rings, you must
>   dispose of them. You may transfer
>   management to another member of the
>   ring, or to some other WebRing member,
>   or you may delete a ring that has no
>   members.
>
> Once all your memberships are deleted,
>   you will find the "Delete This User
>   ID" link in the left column of your My
>   Account page. Once you click that
>   link, you will end your membership in
>   WebRing.

Comment: @TerriSager I don't understand your comment. Are you asking what you should use WebRing for? If so, I have no idea.